# Get attribute value for severity in boost::log::sources::severity_logger custom sink backend consume() handler

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

Imagine, you want to use Boost's boost::log::sources::severity_logger with an endpoint that accepts std::string messages plus an unsigned int severity level. Something like a pimped version of [OutputDebugString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa) in the Win32 API. boost::log is quite handy because of it's built in filtering, the stream insertion operator it supports and the possibility to subscribe more than one backend sink.

So I came up with this trivial synchronous custom sink backend where the log message is extracted in the consume() function. I was even able to check if the severity attribute as set by the BOOST_LOG_SEV() macro exists. But I couldn't extract the concrete value for passing it into the SomeLogChannel() handler as an unsigned int, no matter what I tried. For sure I'm missing something totally obvious.

Thanks for all your hints, please find the source code below.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/basic_sink_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/make_shared_object.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;

void SomeLogChannel(unsigned int severity, const std::string& message) {}

class SinkBackend : public sinks::basic_sink_backend<sinks::synchronized_feeding>
{
public:
    explicit SinkBackend() {}
    void consume(logging::record_view const& rec)
    {
        unsigned int sev;
        std::string message = *rec[boost::log::expressions::smessage];
        if (rec.attribute_values().count("Severity"))
        {
            // How to get the value of the (built in) severity attribute?
            // severity = rec.attribute_values()["Severity"].extract<unsigned int>(); // cannot convert from 'boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::value_ref<T,TagT>' to 'int' with  T=int, TagT=void
            // sev = rec["Severity"].extract<unsigned int>().get(); // Throws exception.
        }
        SomeLogChannel(sev, message);
    }
};

void init_logging()
{
    typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<SinkBackend> sink_t;
    boost::shared_ptr<logging::core> core = logging::core::get();
    boost::shared_ptr<SinkBackend> backend(new SinkBackend());
    boost::shared_ptr<sink_t> sink(new sink_t(backend));
    core->add_sink(sink);
    core->set_filter(logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::error);
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
    init_logging();
    boost::log::sources::severity_logger< logging::trivial::severity_level > lg;
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, logging::trivial::trace) << "Trace message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, logging::trivial::error) << "Error message";
    return 0;
}
```

Following Andrey Semashev's excellent advice, I came up with this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/basic_sink_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/make_shared_object.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/manipulators/add_value.hpp>

void SomeLogChannel(boost::log::trivial::severity_level severity, const std::string& message) {}

enum class tVerbosity { eSilent = 0, eBrief, eVerbose };
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(attr_verbosity, "Verbosity", tVerbosity)

class SinkBackend : public boost::log::sinks::basic_sink_backend<boost::log::sinks::synchronized_feeding>
{
public:
    void consume(boost::log::record_view const& rec)
    {
        boost::log::trivial::severity_level sev = boost::log::trivial::info;
        tVerbosity verbosity = tVerbosity::eVerbose;
        std::string message;
        if (rec[boost::log::expressions::smessage]) message = *rec[boost::log::expressions::smessage];
        if (rec[boost::log::trivial::severity]) sev = *rec[boost::log::trivial::severity];
        if (rec[attr_verbosity]) verbosity = *rec[attr_verbosity]; // Just for debug purposes.
        SomeLogChannel(sev, message);
    }
};

void init_logging()
{
    typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<SinkBackend> sink_t;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::core> core = boost::log::core::get();
    boost::shared_ptr<SinkBackend> backend(new SinkBackend());
    boost::shared_ptr<sink_t> sink(new sink_t(backend));
    core->add_sink(sink);
    core->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity > boost::log::trivial::debug);
    sink->set_filter(attr_verbosity > tVerbosity::eSilent); // Does not seem to work: filters out everything.
}

#define MY_LOG(lg, severity, verbosity) BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, severity) << boost::log::add_value("Verbosity", (tVerbosity)(verbosity))

int main(int, char* [])
{
    init_logging();
    boost::log::sources::severity_logger< boost::log::trivial::severity_level > lg;
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, boost::log::trivial::trace) << "Trace message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, boost::log::trivial::error) << "Error message";
    MY_LOG(lg, boost::log::trivial::info, tVerbosity::eBrief) << "BlahBlahBlah";
    return 0;
}
```

which works like a charm. With the exception of my effort to filter on a custom attribute ("Verbosity"), which unfortunately seems to filter out *all* messages. The value itself arrives in the consume() function, but as soon as I apply the filter, all messages are gone. It seems so simple, yet is so hard... ;-)

Perhaps Andrey can solve this puzzle as well? Many thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

On order to extract an attribute value from the log record, you have to match not only the attribute name but also the value type. This is important because the compile-time information about the value type is lost when the attribute value is stored in the log record, and the extractor must know the type to be able to access the value in a well-defined manner.

In your code, the severity attribute value has type `logging::trivial::severity_level`, not `unsigned int`, as evidenced by the type you use as the severity level in the `severity_logger` template. So, at the point of extraction of this attribute value you should specify that type:

```
void consume(logging::record_view const& rec)
{
    unsigned int sev;
    std::string message = *rec[boost::log::expressions::smessage];
    if (logging::value_ref< logging::trivial::severity_level > severity =
        rec["Severity"].extract< logging::trivial::severity_level >())
    {
        // Convert the enum to unsigned int
        sev = static_cast< unsigned int >(*severity);
    }
    else
    {
        // Either "Severity" attribute not found, or it has value type
        // other than logging::trivial::severity_level. Use a default level.
        sev = 0;
    }

    SomeLogChannel(sev, message);
}
```

However, to avoid duplication it is better to use attribute keywords. A keyword encapsulates information about the attribute name and value type. Conveniently, you're already using the right keyword in your filter, so we might as well use it to extract the value in the sink backend:

```
void consume(logging::record_view const& rec)
{
    unsigned int sev;
    std::string message = *rec[boost::log::expressions::smessage];
    if (auto severity = rec[logging::trivial::severity])
    {
        // Convert the enum to unsigned int
        sev = static_cast< unsigned int >(*severity);
    }
    else
    {
        // Either "Severity" attribute not found, or it has value type
        // other than logging::trivial::severity_level. Use a default level.
        sev = 0;
    }

    SomeLogChannel(sev, message);
}
```

By the way, the same approach applies to extracting the log record message, where you use the `smessage` keyword. However, it should be noted that the message is just another attribute value, which may be missing or have an unexpected type, so it is a good idea to check if it's present and can be extracted before using it (i.e. before dereferencing the `value_ref` returned from `rec[smessage]`).

---

On the updated part, the problem here is that the "Verbosity" attribute is not present in the log record at the point of filtering, in all three log records you make. If an attribute that participates in a filtering expression is not found (or has an unexpected value type), that expression returns `false`, which in your case means the log record is suppressed. This is why the `attr_verbosity > tVerbosity::eSilent` filter rejects all log records.

As to why the attribute is missing, the first two log records you make are made through `severity_logger`, which doesn't add this attribute, and you don't add it either. In the third log record, you use `add_value` manipulator to add it, but that manipulator only adds it [after filtering is done](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/why_attribute_manips_dont_affect_filters.html) (i.e. the manipulator doesn't work as the record is already rejected).

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey Semashev. That was excellent help and works like a charm. I have updated my question accordingly and also added a paragraph with a problem to filter on custom attributes which seemed simple to do but has me ending up with filtering all log messages...

Comment: @Volker You should ask a separate question for each issue you have. I'll let it slide for the first time, but please avoid doing this in future.

Comment: @Volker I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Makes sense. And of course I'll open a new question next time.